# HashiCorpVaultLookupXPathFunctionProvider cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v182

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, apache-synapse, wso2-integration-studio

I am currently using wso2 integration studio 8.0.0 to develop a service and integration project works solid in in my local both in integration studio runtime and local docker engine. However, when I build my docker image push it to the Kubernetes cluster, pod raises error

> WARN {XpathExtensionUtil} - Error while initializing Synapse Xpath
> extension providers java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediation.security.vault.external.hashicorp.HashiCorpVaultLookupXPathFunctionProvider
> cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v182

Other developers in my team are not getting this error in their integration projects. Only difference we could find is the version of integration studio.
In order to fix this error, I placed org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediation.security jar file in my docker exporter libs folder. After deploying my docker image to cluster, Pod changed its error to

> java.lang.abstractmethod” for
> axis2SynapseEnvironment.setXpathVariableExtensions.

I checked source code from github but it seems to be that this is not a abstract method. However, it is an abstract in apache documentation. I am trying to solve this problem but could not resolve it and now I am blocked in my tasks for days .
I would really really appreciate if you could me guide me out of this problem. From which path  does the integration studio resolve synapse dependencies in build time? Which version of synapse core should be used to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the docker base image as `wso2/wso2mi:4.0.0`. Seems you are using Micro Integrator 1.2.0 runtime in your Docker container and note that feature is not available in the 1.2.0 GA release. Please refer to [documentation](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/security/using-hashicorp-secrets/).

Note that, Integration Studio v8.0.0 uses `wso2/wso2mi:4.0.0` and Integration Studio v7.1.0v7.2.0 use `wso2/wso2mi:1.2.0` as the Docker base image.

Comment: I have been using wso2/wso2mi:4.0.0 as my base image all along. Can it be related to different versions of wso2 synapse releases?

Comment: No can not be. If the console log says class not found in synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v182, means you are using Micro Integrator 1.2.0 release. Therefore, please check the runtime version again. Otherwise, you have to get the updated 1.2.0 image from the WSO2 Docker registry to use this feature.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the relation between the synapse core version and the Micro-integrator version.  I was configuring the docker exporter as wso2mi4.0.0 in integration studio however I found that it is statically configured as 1.2.0 (as you mentioned) in my jenkinsfile. After updating the jenkinsfile to use the base image configuration from my docker exporter file in the integration studio, I successfully deployed the pod. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for clarifying the relation between the synapse core version and the Micro-integrator version. I was configuring the docker exporter as wso2mi4.0.0 in integration studio however I found that it is statically configured as 1.2.0 (as you mentioned) in my jenkinsfile. After updating the jenkinsfile to use the base image configuration from my docker exporter file in the integration studio, I successfully deployed the pod. Thanks a lot for your help.